# Install debug .apk programmatically

Tags: android, installation, apk, release

I am developing an Android app which is not on play store. Due to that i have made my own mechanism of updating the app through DownloadManager and then install it.
In order to do that what should be the state of the .apk so that the Android system be able to install it? 
Debug, Release, Signed, Unsigned..?

Comment: Signed release build